# How to select listbox item by pressing enter key?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

IDE: Visual studio 2010, c# .net 4.0, winforms appication:

In my application I am showing list box. now I want to select a default item in  list box [listbox selected index changed event will be called] ]when user presses enter key from keyboard.

Comment: Handle the KeyPress event and set the selected item. What is the problem?

Comment: Where will the focus be? Does it matter? Has the Form KeyPreview on?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where the Enter needs to be caught :

I take the KeyUp event, valid events here are the KeyPress, KeyDown and KeyUp events

```
public class YourFormOrControllerName : Form //Or UserControl
{
    private int yourDefaultValue = 0;
    public YourFormOrControllerName()
    {
        //whenever you haven't selected a specific control to setup (not a so good solution)
        //YourFormOrControllerName.KeyUp += HandleKeyUpSelected;

        //Whenever you Enter in the ListBox
        YourListBoxControlName.KeyUp += HandleKeyUpSelected;
    }

    private void HandleKeyUpSelected(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            YourListBoxControlName.SelectedIndex = yourDefaultValue;
        }
    }
}
```

as @Nyerguds commented below there are different arguments for the different events. For more information i refer to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control_events(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `KeyPress` has `KeyPressEventArgs` though, which gives a Char and not a key code.

Comment: KeyUp, not KeyPress

Comment: Yes, but you mention `KeyPress` as other possibility in your answer.

Comment: @Nyerguds As i mentioned in the example there are different events. and I specified a working code example for the KeyUp event. OP never mentioned anything else so ... (but i added the MSDN events link for more clarification)